# How do I get the size from the beginning of TextView to the beginning of the content in Android?

Tags: android, textview

I want to get a size from the beginning of TextView to the beginning of the content. 
[image] 
But I can't come up with anything. is it possible to get the size?

Answer (score 0):

To get the distance from the start of the button to the start of the text in the button, you can use the `getPaddingLeft()` method of the Button class to get the size of the padding from the start edge of the button, and then use the `getCompoundDrawables()` method to get the array of drawables for the button.

The first element in the array is the drawable to the left of the text, so you can use its getIntrinsicWidth() method to get the width of the drawable.

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
int paddingStart = button.getPaddingLeft();
Drawable[] drawables = button.getCompoundDrawables();
int drawableWidth = drawables[0].getIntrinsicWidth(); // get width of 
drawable to the left of text
int distance = paddingStart + drawableWidth; // total distance from start of button to start of text
```

`distance` should be the distance from the start edge of the button to the start of the text.
I haven't tried this way myself, so let me know if it works :)

Comment: Thnak you for answering! Your approach seems good but if we don't add any drawable into the TextView or Button, `getCompoundDrawables()` return NullPointException.